# Steam (Dota2, CSGO) not launching after 16.10 upgrade from 16.04

Tags: steam, 16.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04. 
Apparently after the upgrade, Steam is not launching.

Can someone please help? Do I need to replace/enable/disable any package/file?

Please help, everything was working perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04

Tried launching Steam via Terminal, below was the ouput:

```
shobhit@shobhit-Inspiron-N5010:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/shobhit/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: I am trying to launch Steam from Ubuntu Dashboard icon.
No error is getting displayed.

Comment: @OwenHines Done

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal

```
nano fix_steam
```

Paste this

```
#!/bin/bash

find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" \) -print -delete

find . -name libgpg-error.so.0 -exec rm {} \;
```

Ctrl+O to save, then Ctrl+X to exit

```
chmod +x fix_steam
```

^ make the script executable

```
./fix_steam
```

^ run the script

This simple script deletes some of the (out of date) shared libraries (like windows dll's) than steam installs, which are built to work with 14.04 I think. The so's are incompatible with your system, you have newer versions installed so you can just delete the steam ones and Linux will pick up your new ones.